# PHP QRCode Library: how to link to download SVG file?

Tags: php, svg, qr-code

I have HTML links like this:

`<a href="http://mysite.xyz/getqr.php?id=123456">`

I need that the activated link downloads the SVG file.
*getqr.php* at this time shows the SVG onscreen

```
require_once('qrlib.php');
$theurl = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$urlarray = parse_url($theurl);
parse_str($urlarray['query'], $queryarray);
$theqrid = $queryarray['id'];
$dataText = 'http://dest.mysite.xyz/qr?id='.$theqrid;
echo QRcode::svg($dataText);
```

Whats needs to be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options. Either handle the QR code image as an attachment in PHP (here I assume a PNG will be the result):

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=qrcode.jpg');
header('Content-type: image/png');

require_once('qrlib.php');
$theurl = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$urlarray = parse_url($theurl);
parse_str($urlarray['query'], $queryarray);
$theqrid = $queryarray['id'];
$dataText = 'http://dest.mysite.xyz/qr?id='.$theqrid;
echo QRcode::svg($dataText);
```

or set the download attribute on the link:

```
<a href="http://mysite.xyz/getqr.php?id=123456" download="qrcode.png">QR code</a>
```

Comment: I needed 'svg' so i tried this:
```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=qrcode.svg');
header('Content-type: image/svg+xml');
```
It doesn't works.
BUT the `download` parameter in the link does what i need (probably have some limit on older browsers but this is not a constrain for me)